# How to set up a user profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, constants

I declared a constant to make my userID readable but Xcode is forcing me to unwrap userID to make my code valid how do I fix this error

> Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value
>   contains 'nil'

```
DatabaseRef = Database.database().reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
DatabaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because 'currentUser' is optional:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```

Either force-unwrap it or provide a default value on data type using '??'.

You could also try using 'if let' or 'guard' statement.

Go through this documentation for it:

> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html